# Converting dt.time() to timedelta data type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert my column 'Time' to the correct timedelta data type so I can use comparisons to drop certain times out of the data frame later in the code, but I am coming across a ValueError "ValueError: Could not convert 'Time' to NumPy timedelta"

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time (earliest)']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time (earliest)']).dt.time


df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(['Time'])
```

The first two lines work, but the last does not...

[dataframe output before error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2MhJ.jpg)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ... Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: How will you use that column for comparisons?

Comment: What's your expected output? For example, what do you want to obtain when you use `pd.to_timedelta(['Time'])` on the first value of the column "Time"?